# Upgrading to Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS from live USB fails

Tags: boot, 16.04, dell, live-usb, inspiron

Hardware Dell Inspiron 15-3552 with full details from lspci shown at the end of this message. The PC is factory loaded with Ubuntu 14 LTS.

I have prepared a live USB stick from the iso image of Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS. When I try to boot from this stick I select the option "Try ubuntu", and continue. The system then goes through a splash screen, displaying the logo for Ubuntu, with moving dots indicating activity. But after about ten seconds the system dies with completely black screen. I have updated to the latest version BIOS from Dell, but did not observe any improvement.

I'd like to ask if there is a fix for this problem, and if not is there a chance of a fix at some future date, or should I just give up. Grateful for any suggestions.

---

Hardware details are:

- 00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 2280 (rev 21)
- 00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b1 (rev
  21)
- 00:0b.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 22dc
  (rev 21)
- 00:13.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 22a3 (rev 21)
- 00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 22b5 (rev 21)
- 00:1a.0 Encryption controller: Intel Corporation Device 2298 (rev 21)
- 00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 2284 (rev 21)
- 00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 22c8 (rev 21)
- 00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 229c (rev 21)
- 00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 2292 (rev 21)
- 01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565
  Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)

Comment: I also have a Dell laptop and it is setup so that I cannot install a running Ubuntu from USB. You have to use their partition provided Ubuntu and update via Internet. Mine came with 12.04, so the last time I reset it it took me a while. Another thing you can try is to setup the USB key as a source and then run the update.

Comment: @RamonSuarez thank you for your comments. Few points: 1. "try Ubuntu" option does not try to change existing partitions, and leaves the HDD entirely unaffected. 2. Could you explain what you mean by setting up USB "as a source"? 3. I have quite successfully tried Kubuntu 14 from USB, which suggests that the problem is version 16.

Comment: Start the computer with your Ubuntu inbthe hard disk, then do the update to the new release from there. When apt or any software manager looks for packages it goes into its list of sources, the repositories from which you can download: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Repositories/Ubuntu

Comment: Why do you want to upgrade from the USB and not through Ubuntu's own  update system? You just need an internet connection.

Comment: @RamonSuarez I know I can upgrade by using the package manager as opposed to a fresh install. However, that is a risky option, as I could end up with the current system being trashed and the new system not correctly installed. In fact, on one occasion the regular updater offered me that option, and in a moment of madness, I accepted. Consequently the whole system was trashed, and I had to rebuild everything up from scratch

Comment: @RamonSuarez My method is usually: 1. try from startup USB. 2. Install a new system side by side of the old. 3. Install a new system overwriting the previous two. That is as safe as one can get, and the USB is preserved to recover from a future crash. I also want to know the technical reason why the method I have chosen has not worked.

Comment: Then your heading is not right: you are having problems with a fresh install, not upgrading.

Comment: @RamonSuarez Mea Culpa; however, in a wider sense, I needed to indicate that the pc is already running under a fully functioning Ubuntu 14, and I want to migrate to Ubuntu 16.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same issue from 1 year now on my Inspiron 5567 Kaby Lake 7500U.

The secret to install Ubuntu/Debian/any linux distrib on new Inspiron 5567 Kaby Lake is here: you need to create a special boot setup.

#### For a dual boot with a Windows 10 preinstalled :

1. Burn your iso with Rufus (mostly GPT mode for laptop after 2013, config autoselected by default in Rufus. Change to MBR if the pc is older),
2. Go in your USB key and enter the EFI  and please notice the name of the files here...as grubx64.efi (unsecure boot) or shimx64.efi (secure boot). You will need this info later.
3. Restart the PC with the USB plugged in. When the Dell logo appears, hit <kbd>F12</kbd> till you see the boot menu. If you can see your USB key here, **don't select it**. First, enter the BIOS by selecting **bios setup**.
4. Go on **Boot Sequence**, you need to ensure the BIOS is set to UEFI, disable **Legacy option ROMS** and check that secure boot is enabled on the **Secure Boot Enable** line.
5. Now the most important operation... come back to **Boot Sequence** (**General** menu on the left)

   - click on <kbd>Add Boot Option</kbd>. The Add Boot Option window will pop up. Type a name in the Boot Option Name text area ("Ubuntu", for example).
   - Click the button to the left of the File Name text area. The EFI Boot Selection window will pop up.
   - In the File System drop down menu choose **FS0:** and **EFI**. Then using the directories section, navigate until you can choose `SHIMx64.EFI` (for Ubuntu only - for other distros use `grubx64.efi` or `grubx.efi` if your PC is not amd64, anyway it will be named `grubxxxxx.efi`) in the Files section.
6. A new boot option will now appear on the top and in the boot menu. Save and exit
7. The pc will now restart, when the Dell logo is coming, press <kbd>F12</kbd> again, till the boot menu appears. Select the name you entered in the previous step (NOT the USB key)
8. The GUI installer will come up and you can run it

If it does not work for you exactly like this, try disabling secure boot in the BIOS.